# (Angular 7) Cannot assign to read only property 'isActive' on ng-block-ui

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the ng-block-ui dependency for my project. The problem is that it doesn't work properly on Angular 7. I have used this on an Angular 6 project and works fine

app.module.ts

```
import { BlockUIModule } from 'ng-block-ui';


@NgModule({
     BlockUIModule.forRoot()
})
```

component.ts

```
import { BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';

export class *classname* implements OnInit {
     @BlockUI('departure') blockUIList: NgBlockUI;

     constructor() { this.blockUIList.start('Loading Page...'); }
}
```

component.html

```
<div class="kt-portlet kt-portlet--mobile" *blockUI="'departure'">
```

## Error Message

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'isActive' of object '[object Object]'
    at BlockUIInstanceService.push../node_modules/ng-block-ui/fesm5/ng-block-ui.js.BlockUIInstanceService.blockUIMiddleware (ng-block-ui.js:113)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at ReplaySubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at ReplaySubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/ReplaySubject.js.ReplaySubject.nextInfiniteTimeWindow (ReplaySubject.js:39)
    at Object.stop (ng-block-ui.js:131)
    at SafeSubscriber._complete (booking-reservation.component.ts:125)
    at SafeSubscriber.wrappedComplete (Subscriber.js:175)
```

Comment: Remove the `node_modules` and then run this command 'npm install'. I hope it helps you out.

Comment: @YashRami already did but the error is still there.

Comment: do you add the plugin blockui

Comment: @ORBIT if you mean I added it to the package.json file, then yes.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ngBlockUi? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui

Comment: @Tim Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with it.

I am in error when changing isActive = true from fesm5 / ng-block-ui.js in ng-block-ui.

It's not a perfect solution, `ng-block-ui.js` -> Line: 114 [this.blockUIInstances[name].isActive = isActive] ==> this.blockUIInstances[name] = Object.assign({}, this.blockUIInstances[name], {isActive: isActive}) you can fix it without errors.